# Using 2 Calendar class instances to get time difference

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I am using the Calendar library within Java to try and figure out a problem with my application:

I have two Calendar instances, `depart` and `arrive`.

`depart` is leaving at **5:35 pm on 7/15/2015** from Chicago, while `arrive` is landing at **9:50 am on 7/16/15** in Berlin, Germany.

My current code to display the travel duration is:

```
    Calendar depart = Calendar.getInstance();       
    Calendar arrive = Calendar.getInstance();

    depart.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
    arrive.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

    depart.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
    depart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
    depart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    depart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);

    arrive.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
    arrive.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);
    arrive.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    arrive.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);

System.out.println("Depart: " + depart.getTime() + "\nArrive: " + arrive.getTime());

long hours = (arrive.getTimeInMillis() - depart.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000*60*60);
long minutes = (arrive.getTimeInMillis() - depart.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000*60) - (hours*60);

System.out.println("Flight duration: " + hours + " hours" + " " + minutes + " minutes");`
```

and the result is:

`Depart: Wed Jul 15 17:35:53 CDT 2015
Arrive: Thu Jul 16 02:50:53 CDT 2015
Flight duration: 9 hours 15 minutes`

...But I need the result to be:

`Depart: Wed Jul 15 17:35:53 CDT 2015
Arrive: Thu Jul 16 **09:50:53 Central European Timezone** 2015
Flight duration: 9 hours 15 minutes`

**I need to change both depart and arrive so they display their local time, but still report the correct travel duration of 9 hours and 15 minutes.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `getTime()` to get a `Date` instance, and then calling `toString()` on that, implicitly - that will *always* use the system local time zone.

You want to use `SimpleDateFormat` so that you can control the time zone used for formatting. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z", Locale.US);
formatter.setTimeZone(depart.getTimeZone());
System.out.println("Depart: " + formatter.format(depart.getTime()));
formatter.setTimeZone(arrive.getTimeZone());
System.out.println("Arrive: " + formatter.format(arrive.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am using the Calendar library within Java to try and figure out a
> problem with my application

You should have used `java.time` API which had been already in use for more than a year when you posted your question.

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

> ... leaving at 5:35 pm on 7/15/2015 from Chicago, while arrive is
> landing at 9:50 am on 7/16/15 in Berlin, Germany ...
> ... to display the travel duration

You can create `ZonedDateTime` instances and find the `Duration` between them.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime depart = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2015, 7, 15, 17, 35), ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
        ZonedDateTime arrive = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2015, 7, 16, 9, 50), ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
        Duration duration = Duration.between(depart, arrive);
        System.out.println("Depart: " + depart);
        System.out.println("Arrive: " + arrive);
        System.out.printf("Flight duration: %d hours %d minutes%n", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart());

        //An example of a custom format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(depart.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Depart: 2015-07-15T17:35-05:00[America/Chicago]
Arrive: 2015-07-16T09:50+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
Flight duration: 9 hours 15 minutes
Wed Jul 15 17:35:00 CDT 2015
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/OUyAcS)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormat`s to present your dates as you wish:

```
DateFormat departDF = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
    DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, Locale.US
);
departDF.setTimeZone(depart.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(departDF.format(depart.getTime()));
DateFormat arriveDF = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
    //                                change to US if you want them homologated
    //                                it won't change the time zone info or date/time
    DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, Locale.GERMANY
);
arriveDF.setTimeZone(arrive.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(arriveDF.format(arrive.getTime()));
```

**Output**

```
July 15, 2015 5:35:43 PM CDT
16. Juli 2015 09:50:43 CEST
```