# Timezone issue within Java Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, dst, difference

I am using two instances of Calendar, and trying to get the time between each instance (I am calling the instances `depart` and `arrive`).

Here is a code snippet that I am focusing on:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Calendar departDST = Calendar.getInstance();
    departDST.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    departDST.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
    departDST.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
    departDST.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    departDST.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);

    Calendar arriveDST = Calendar.getInstance();
    arriveDST.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    arriveDST.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
    arriveDST.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);
    arriveDST.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    arriveDST.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);

    departDST.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
    arriveDST.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    printFlightDuration(departDST, arriveDST);
}

public static void printFlightDuration(Calendar depart, Calendar arrive)
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z", Locale.US);

    formatter.setTimeZone(depart.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println("Depart: " + formatter.format(depart.getTime()));

    formatter.setTimeZone(arrive.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println("Arrive: " + formatter.format(arrive.getTime()));

    long hours = (arrive.getTimeInMillis() - depart.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000*60*60);
    long minutes = (arrive.getTimeInMillis() - depart.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000*60) - (hours*60);

    System.out.println("Flight duration: " + hours + " hours" + " " + minutes + " minutes");
}
```

Now, if I set the date of `depart` to be **7/15/2015 at 5:35 pm** and `arrive` to be **7/16/2015 at 9:50 am**, the application reports the correct time of *9 hours and 15 minutes*.

If I set the date of `depart` to be **3/7/2015 at 5:35 pm** and `arrive` to be **3/8/2015 at 9:50 am**, the application reports in at *10 hours and 15 minutes* [because of daylights savings time occurring at 2:00 am on 3/8/2015].

How should I change my application so that it reports the correct duration of 9 hours 15 minutes, regardless of which date I set  `depart` and `arrive` to?

- One idea I had was to convert to `depart` and `arrive` to UTC, and then calculate the difference between them but either I implemented the solution incorrectly or the solution altogether is an incorrect answer to the problem

Comment: Change the Locale.US to Some other country where daylight savings are not followed

Comment: Is this question different to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120039/using-2-calendar-class-instances-to-get-time-difference ?

Comment: @tilois Yes, the first was a question of formatting that was resolved. This is a different question.

Comment: @Madhan I need the locale to stay consistent. I need my 'depart' to take off from Chicago, and 'arrive' to land in a UTC timezone.

Comment: But other than your issue..Month is 0 index based means if you give 2 it means March[2] not February[1][January[0]]

Comment: @Madhan The locale has nothing to do with timezones and is only responsible for localized week-related.calculations in `java.util.GregorianCalendar`.